# How to install C++ dependencies for the arrow package?

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I am trying to download a package in an linux-based R session (I also have terminal access).  It requires specific C++ dependency but I am unable to find out how to install them.

Since I am behind a company's server, they have restricted our access to the web.  And all packages have an artifactory that I have to point to inorder to download packages.

For example: I've been able to set change the repo in this way to install packages from CRAN (I've masked the *** of the website):

```
r <- getOption("repos")
r["CRAN"] <- "https://***.***.***/artifactory/r-project-cran/"
options(repos = r)
options(download.file.method = "curl")
options(download.file.extra = "--insecure")
```

But now I am having trouble with a specific dependency that's needed for one of the packages. Specifically the "arrow" package.

For example, I went:

```
install.packages("arrow", dependencies=TRUE,type="source")
Installing package into ‘/***/***/R’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://***.***.***/artifactory/list/cran-r/src/contrib:
  Line starting '{ ...' is malformed!
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 4662k  100 4662k    0     0  5268k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 5262k
* installing *source* package ‘arrow’ ...
** package ‘arrow’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: github.com
*** Proceeding without C++ dependencies
------------------------- NOTE ---------------------------
There was an issue preparing the Arrow C++ libraries.
See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/install.html
---------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘arrow’
* removing ‘/***/***/R/arrow’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpu2u1d3/downloaded_packages’
```

1. Does anyone know the specific steps I need to take to resolve this issue?
2. Is there a way to change the curl command and point it to the company's artifactory for github?
3. Or alternatively, installing the arrow C++ library before hand?

Answer (score 1):

If you can control what version of `arrow` is put in your artifactory server, you could prepare a "fat" source package of arrow that includes all C++ dependencies. This is a new utility function that was added in arrow 6.0.0. See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/create_package_with_all_dependencies.html for instructions on how to do this.

You could also install official Apache Arrow system packages, as described on https://arrow.apache.org/install/. The downside here is that you have to keep the versions of those libraries and the R package in sync; if you upgrade one without the other, it will not work. https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/install.html discusses this further.

Comment: Hey Neal!  Thank you for getting back to me.  I just faced an issue where I followed the instructions in creating a "fat" pacakge... but it seems like its broken.  I tried it in different computers===>
Error in create_package_with_all_dependencies("my_arrow_pkg.tar.gz") : 
  Failed to download thirdparty dependencies

Comment: Would you know if the function is broken?  I tried it in my computer at home as well, and the same thing.

Comment: We do [test this workflow](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/9064fa0cccd240d30ad243daded9d84825983c83/dev/tasks/r/github.linux.offline.build.yml#L61) in our CI, but looking at the function, it would be nice if it would give you more verbose output in case it failed. Would you mind [opening a JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW) so we can look into this?